# Can't import .h file from Tapku

Tags: iphone, ios, tapku

I am trying to use Tapku and I did exactly as the official instructions say,but whenever I import a .h file, Xcode says it can't find it?

Is there any possible reason for this

https://github.com/devinross/tapkulibrary/wiki/Adding-tapku-to-your-project-in-xcode-4

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that a path to their header file is in the "Header Search Paths" for your target in Xcode.

Answer (score 2):

Check your folder name.
When you put `$(SRCROOT)` in the `Header Search Paths`, it will show you the actual path.

**And if there is any space in the folder name, it will cause the problem.**

I was almost giving up to add the library, then I tried this method and it worked like charm.  :)
In my case, my project was under `iPhone Apps` folder, and I had to change it to `iPhoneApps` by removing the space.